# how to Modify image on html form submission. The image is pre-loaded on a servlet url

Tags: html, ajax, jsp, servlets

I have an image servlet which basically loads an image template on a url.
i am also able to access it through img tag.

Based on my response after form submission, i need to display this image
Following is an excerpt from my ajax code

```
  document.getElementById("outmessage").innerHTML = "<h2><img src=\"${pageContext.request.contextPath}/sort-code-image\"/> </h2>";
```

I basically need to modify/draw on this image template before i display it on my jsp page.
I am a bit confused as to how to proceed with this problem.
Do i modify the image on servlet everytime when i do some of my business logic
or is there a better way to do this?

Apologies for some terminologies as i am a bit new to servlet and ajax.

Any inputs is highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can use the following to write a base64 encoded data to img src attribute in java script and can modify the image.

```
var src3="data:image/jpg;base64,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";
document.getElementById("outmessage").innerHTML = "<h2> Image \<img src\= "+src3+" /></h2>";
```

I figured out the same when i faced the problem mentioned in following link

[setting variable value in src attribute of image tag to a base64 encoded image in javascript/ajax](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13694234/setting-variable-value-in-src-attribute-of-image-tag-to-a-base64-encoded-image-i)