# setting variable value in src attribute of image tag to a base64 encoded image in javascript/ajax

Tags: javascript, html, ajax, image, src

I have an image byte code base64 encoded which i am trying to set the  tag's src attribute in the javascript/ajax.

I don't want to directly set it as i am getting this byte code from reading the response back from a servlet and taking the bytecode into a variable and want to set this variables value in 
the src attribute like following.

```
var src3="data:image/jpg;base64,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";
document.getElementById("outmessage").innerHTML = "<h2> Image \<img src\= "+src3+" /></h2>";
```

This doesn't work:
gives me an output as

[image]

The thing i am sure about is that the base64 byte is correct as i tested it by adding
directly to the src element of img tag like following

```
<img src ="data:image/jpg;base64,/9j/4AAQSkZJRgABAQEAYABgAAD/2wBDAAgGBgcGBQgHBwcJCQgKDBQNDAsLDBkSEw8UHRofHh0a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"> </img>
```

I am not sure how to set this in javascript from a variable.
Can someone give any pointers as to how this can be achieved?
Thanks in advance

Comment: You've a space between `<img src\=` and `"+src3+" />`, remove it. Even better, add quotes. Even better, use [`document.createElement`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/document.createElement).

Comment: Removing the space or adding quotes doesn't solve the problem, string gets truncated, thats why you get no image at all.

Comment: @VoidMain http://jsfiddle.net/8wxSs/ works fine with no space and quotes?

Comment: Your base64 data seems to be corrupted, and/or incomplete... A working example here: http://jsfiddle.net/LnBzX/ with some data converted with http://www.motobit.com/util/base64-decoder-encoder.asp

Comment: Curious enough, in the same browser i'm using, when using it along with Ext (i was doing the test on a page from an app i'm devloping) that doesn't work, string always get truncated...

Comment: I see, there is an error in your `var src3=...` declaration, there is something wrong with the data, if i copy the data from your var it doesn't work, but it works if i copy the data thats just below and fix the newlines.

Comment: space wasn't the issue...checking the rest of them.....The base64 data also seems to be fine as i printed the same in another html page....

Comment: even i ran my code in http://jsfiddle.net/8wxSs/ it work fine...not sure what the problem is......

Comment: i was running the same pieces of code through eclipse (deploying on tomcat) and was checking the result page on eclipse default browser.There it was not displaying the image. When i ran the same url in firefox or chrome,it displayed the image. I guess some problem with eclipse default browser not being able to show the image. A bit weird. Has anyone faced this issue?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
var src3="data:image/jpg;base64,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";
document.getElementById("outmessage").innerHTML = "<h2> Image \<img src\= "+src3+" /></h2>";
```

The above works in the browsers (ie/firefox etc).
i was running the same pieces of code through eclipse (deploying on tomcat) and was checking the result page on eclipse default browser.There it was not displaying the image. When i ran the same url in firefox or chrome,it displayed the image. I guess some problem with eclipse default browser not being able to show the image